# Bean Validator Component Constraints

Tags: java

Hi I want to know how to restrict a field to accept particular values. Lets say if there a Bean

```
class Student{
    @NotNull
    private int id;
    // Country should be either India or USA
    private String Country;
}
```

Please let me know if you are aware of any annotation to be used for the country field. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use enumeration if you wants to limit the choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [afzalex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3626698/afzalex) said, use an enumeration to limit the choices. You can use a custom Bean Validation Constraint `public @interface CountryConstraint` to specify the allowed enumeration entries and then implement a constraint validator `public class CountryValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CountryConstraint, Country>` to validate the values. [Here](http://softwarecave.org/2014/03/27/custom-bean-validation-constraints/) and [here](http://www.javabeat.net/bean-validation-java-ee-creating-custom-constraints-validations/) is a completes example on how to achieve this.